# Динамическая смена option для select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Привет, каким образом можно сделать чтобы, `$obj->rid` из первого селекта, подставлялся вместо `$selects[1]` по второй, и так же с третьим.
Смысл в том, чтобы сначала набор селектов был как в начальном коде, а при смене пользователем, менялся. Спасибо)

```
$sql = "select rparent, rid, rname_ru FROM rubrics_new";
$selects = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo "<select name='first'>";

foreach($selects[0] as $obj ) { 
    echo "<option value='$obj->rid'>$obj->rname_ru</option>";
} 

echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='second'>";

foreach($selects[1] as $obj ) {
    echo "<option value='$obj->rid'>$obj->rname_ru</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='third'>"; 

foreach($selects[10] as $obj ) {
    echo "<option value='$obj->rid'>$obj->rname_ru</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, смотри, что тебе приблизительно нужно :

Во-первых, тебе надо, чтобы сервер выдавал ява-скрипту данные в json-формате (делается это простыми средстваи php - способы разные есть, в т.ч. встроенная ф-ция, которую я сам почти не проверял, сейчас не помню как она звучит - в общем, найдешь как в корректном формате вывести). На выходе у тебя должен получится json - объект примерно такого вида:

```
    {
    0 : {
       name : "Select 1", val : {
               0: {
                  name : "Select 1.1", val : {
                       0: { name : "Select 1.1.1", val : ""},
                       1: { name : "Select 1.1.2", val : ""},
                       2: { name : "Select 1.1.3", val : ""},
                       3: { name : "Select 1.1.4", val : ""}
                    }//END Val Select 1.1
                }, 
                1: {
                  name : "Select 1.2", val : {
                       0: { name : "Select 1.2.1", val : ""},
                       1: { name : "Select 1.2.2", val : ""},
                       2: { name : "Select 1.2.3", val : ""},
                       3: { name : "Select 1.2.4", val : ""}
                    }//END Val Select 1.2
                },
                2: {
                  name : "Select 1.3", val : {
                       0: { name : "Select 1.3.1", val : ""},
                       1: { name : "Select 1.3.2", val : ""},
                       2: { name : "Select 1.3.3", val : ""},
                       3: { name : "Select 1.3.4", val : ""}
                    }//END Val Select 1.3
                }
        }//END Val Select 1
    }, 
    1 : {
       name : "Select 2", val : {
               0: {
                  name : "Select 2.1", val : {
                       0: { name : "Select 2.1.1", val : ""},
                       1: { name : "Select 2.1.2", val : ""},
                       2: { name : "Select 2.1.3", val : ""},
                       3: { name : "Select 2.1.4", val : ""}
                    }//END Val Select 2.1
                }, 
                1: {
                  name : "Select 2.2", val : {
                       [...]
                    }//END Val Select 2.2
                },
                2: {
                  name : "Select 1.3", val : {
                       [...]
                    }//END Val Select 1.3
                }
        }//END Val Select 2
    }, 
    2 : {[...]}
}
```

Корректность потом проверишь через json-валидатор (их полно в интернете)

Эту конструкцию либо (лучший вариант) подгружаешьна отдельной странице (желательно с `header('Content-type: text/json'); header('Content-type: application/json');`), которую потом грузись с помощью js (желательно, используя jQuery $.getJSON() - чтобы не морочиться), либо (менее желательно), загоняешь все это на ту же страницу в <`script>var data = {[...]}</script>` - в любом случае, ты получишь объект var data (или называй его как хочешь), в котором ты всегда можешь найти нужную тебе цепочку:

т.е., если у тебя пользователь выбрал на 1м вареанте 2й пункт (index = 1,т.к. отсчет от 0) - список для 2го select будет находиться в data[1].val с заголовками data[1].val[0].name, data[1].val[1].name ..., для 3 го - в data[1].val[0].val  (data[1].val[0].val[0].name, data[1].val[0].val[1].name ...)

Т.е. html для select 2го select можно получить таким образом

```
 var html = ''; 
 for(var i in data[1].val){ html+='<option>' + data[1].val[i].name + '</option>';}
```

Или с помощью такой функции:

```
 var getOptions = function(dat){
     var html = ''; 
     for(var i in dat.val){ html+='<option>' + dat.val[i].name + '</option>';}
 }

var options0 = getOptions(data);//Для 1го (хотя его тебе перезаписывать не надо)
var options1 = getOptions(data[0].val);//Для 2го
var options2 = getOptions(data[0].val[1]);//Для 3го
```

Переписать любой из селектов - не сложно:

```
//Без jQuery
var select = document.getElementById('selects').getElementsByTagName("select");
select[1].innerHTML = options1;

//C jQuery
var $select = $('#selects select');
$select.eq(1).html(options1);
```

Осталось отследить событиеизменения и отловить какой из select и на что был изменен

```
var select_change =  function () {
    var $select = $('#selects select');// Получаем все select
    var index =  $(this).index(); //Понять с которым по счету мы имеем дело  
    var tmp;//сюда будем пихать временные значения из data
    $select.each(function(i,e){//Прогоняем все select
        //Получаем выбранный элемент в каждом <select>
        var opt =(i<=index) ? $(this).fing('option:selected').index() : 0;//Значение "по умолчанию"  для следующих после выбранного пусть будет 0 (1й элемент)
       if(i==0){tmp = data[opt]; //Если это - 1й селект, его не перезаписываем - просто получаем объект  tmp для следующего
       }else{
          if(i > index && typeof tmp!="undefined"){//Если это след. после измененного и удалось получить tmp
             var options  = getOptions(tmp); //Получам html (ф-цию см выше)
             $(this).html(options);//И загоням все это на место того, что есть сейчас
          }
            tmp = tmp.val[opt];//Получаем объект  tmp для следующего
        }
     });  
 }
 $(document).on('change', '#selects select',select_change);
```

Для js без jQuery - нужно будет видимо прописать onchenge = "select_change(2);" (в скобках - номер селекта (index - чтобы потом не выяснять). Ф-ция select_change тоже будет немного отличаться (for in вместо each и т.д.)

Учти! В написаном мною коде могут быть ошибки: после рабочего дня сидел-писал, голова уже дурная (особенно в select_change). Но общей принцип ты отсюда почерпнуть сможешь и, если что - то разберешься думаю....

Comment: Спасибо, буду заниматься

Comment: Я заполнил массив data.json в том виде в котором у вас в первом окне, и передал его вот так в php: '<?php
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = file_get_contents('data.json');
?>' Правильно?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Если data.json - это у тебя "физический" файл на сервере (или, по крайней мере, сервер может отдать файл data.json), то этот файл прям можешь из js (jQuery) через $.getJSON() попробовать и грузить: по идеи, он его зачастую и без header ловить нормально может (с header - корректнее, к тому же кроссдоменный с header можно сделать)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что до конца понял, что ты хочешь, но попробуй все это запихнуть в цикл и динамически подставлять $selects[$i;]

```
$sel_names = array('first','second','third');
$count= count($selects);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
     echo "<select name='".$sel_names[$i]."'>"; 
     foreach($selects[$i] as $obj ) {
        echo "<option value='$obj->rid'>$obj->rname_ru</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
}
```

И вот в этом случае ты уже сможешь контроллировать что-куда подставляется.
Например, сделав так:

```
[...]
$k = (($k=$i+1)>=$count) ? $k : 0;
foreach($selects[$k] as $obj ) { [...]
```

Comment: Попробую подробнее описать, есть таблица, в которой 3 уровня: 1 уровень выводится в первый селект (id 1,2,3,4,5 parentid у них 0), 2 уровень выводится во второй селект(id 10,11,12,..,52), 3 уровень выводится в третий селект(101,..,122) На экран выводится 3 селекта: 1селект(значения с parentid 0) 2 селект(значения с parentid 1) 3 селект(значения с parentid 10). При смене первого селекта(например выбран пункт с id = 2 ) меняется parentid в селект2 на parentid 2. и так же в селект3. Может что-то разъяснил:)

Comment: Запутал не меньше: т.е. тебе front-end, а не back-end нужен чтоли? Или что? откуда у тебя селект2  parentid 2 будет получать? (если я так понял, у тебя есть  селект1  -> parentid 0, селект2  -> parentid 1 и селект3  -> parentid 10 ).  Как мне пока что кажется, тебе нужно будет отдавать результаты js-скриптам в json-формате (ввиде вложенных объектов) и потом вешать обработчик onchange на <select> с функцией, получающий выбранные значения, отискивающие нужные значения в полученном json-объекте и генерирующие на их основе новые. <select> за место прежних.

Comment: Но, т.к. я все еще не уверен, что понял тебя верно расписывать подробнее пока не хочу

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь, получается что front-end: http://jsfiddle.net/7d15qaqb/2/ тут накидал, может будет понятнее

Comment: Да, так гораздо понятнее. Написал ответ отдельным сообщением